# Ideal value for timeout in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to understand about the ideal value of timeout in awaitTermination() method for executorservice. How should we decide the ideal timeout? Does it harm if we use one day as the timeout?

`boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException;`

suppose I am loading data from one database to another database. Sometimes it may slow down because of network issues and even the number of documents to upload may also increase. So it becomes a little difficult to judge the max time. So in that scenario, if I use one day as a timeout (Actually, I want to use awaitTermination() without a timeout from executorService side). What exactly are the disadvantages of this?

What is the downside of awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS)?

because anyways, executorservice will terminate once the tasks are done

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63739129/use-of-timeout-in-awaittermination-executorservice?noredirect=1#comment112714042_63739129)

Comment: If you want `awaitTermination` without timeout, you can always resort to `awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS)`. Downsides of too long of a timout is generally it could be stopping your app from being closed properly, depending on how executor service is configured and what tasks are inside it. I don't believe there is such thing as "Ideal timout value" for everyone else, only you are supposed to know these things based on other aspects of your app.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, basically I am trying to make a generic framework, which reads data from Cassandra and put it in elasticsearch. So the data in the table varies. So I am using awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS) only. But just wanted to be sure it should not have any problem.

Comment: @PurushottamBaghel If you want to make it as generic as possible, let the user configure it via a property. When set use the property, else resort to a default value

Comment: @Lino, In my case, user is my application only. I expose the Rest endpoint, which can fetch data from any table in Cassandra and bulk upload in elasticsearch

Comment: @PurushottamBaghel, As I said, there's no single value that would suit anyone. So if you are creating a framework, it should have a way to confugure these things, like Lino said.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, should I first fetch the data from cassandra and calculate the size of the data. According to the size, set timeout?

Comment: @PurushottamBaghel, probably not. If you're going to fetch all of it, why not just write it right then? And what happens if there's 100GB of data? 200GB? 3TB?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, Elasticsearch doesn't take all data in one batch. So I am making batches and giving it to executorService. Just not able to decide timeout for that

Comment: Why do you call `awaitTermination` at all?

Comment: @Holger, because I want to know number of records processed

Comment: `awaitTermination` doesn’t tell you, how many records have been processed. That looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: @Holger, you are right!!! awaitTermination is not telling the count. I have different logic for it. AwaitTermination() just stop request from finishing, before executorService finishes all tasks.

Comment: There are better methods for such a purpose, e.g. `invokeAll`. That method has a version without timeout.

Comment: Thanks @Holger, your comments are really helpful. Actually I was doing it wrong in my code. I was using invokeAll(), then shutdown and then awaitTermination(). I think, we need not to call awaitTermination() with invokeAll(). Let me know if my understanding is correct. Thanks again.

Comment: When `invokeAll()` returns, all jobs that were passed in the argument have been completed. When there are no other jobs, you don’t need `awaitTermination`. In fact, even when there are other jobs whose completion state is irrelevant to you, you still don’t need `awaitTermination`.

Comment: @Holger, do we need awaitTermination() while shutting down the executorService?

Comment: Only when you have to do something after the shutdown completed. Otherwise, just let the shutdown go. It will proceed and eventually complete, whether you wait for it or not.

Comment: Thanks @Holger, just the last thing, what is the difference between shutdown and termination. What exactly is isTerminated() and isShutdown() tells?

Comment: shutdown is the process the started when `shutdown` has been called. The executor service is terminated when that process completed.

Comment: @Holger, if that is the case, then why isTerminated() is returning true after invokeAll() completed all process.
`executorService.invokeAll(callables);
executorService.shutdown();
System.out.println("isShutDown "+executorService.isShutdown()); // returns true
System.out.println("isTerminated "+executorService.isTerminated()); // returns false
`

Comment: Shutting down an executor service that has no pending jobs can be very quick.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how long a task can consume.

How long in the worst case you longest task will take?
Lets say it will take in worst case 1 min. Then take 2 min.
You simply calculate worst case time plus a buffer.

You simply don't wont that the started job is canceled without reason because you can get a data loss.

If you are working e.g. on a queue with confirmation and you confirm only if your job is done, you can terminate immediately because on next start and after timeout your worker gets the task again. (But be carefully. If you servere restarts you can end up in a loop)

Comment: I am trying to make a generic framework, which reads data from Cassandra and put it in elasticsearch. So the data in the table varies. So I am not able to decide the timeout for the executorService.

Comment: And you can't do in cassandra something like paging? Maybe you find a way to split in previsible slices. I don't know cassandra. But maybe you want add the tag "cassandra" or ask again with the tag cassandra. I recommend you search for a way to get previsible times. BTW. Why do you want interrupt the process? If I would do such a transfer it would be a one shot action. Or you try something like a sync? You searched for existing tools? Maybe somebody else has done it already.